# How to custom header view that sticky in top screen when scroll UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have the header (header : `UICollectionReusableView`) in my `UICollectionView`. The header has 3 UIView (`UIView1`, `UIView2`, `UIView3`). When I set `collectionLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true`, the header will in top when I scroll the collection. And I want when the header stick in top of `UICollectionView`, I will hide `UIView1` and `UIView2`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. This means that is you assign a delegate to it then this delegate may listen to `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` method which will be called every time the offset changes in your collection view.

On this event you will need to get all of your header views which I assume you may get by calling `visibleSupplementaryViews` on your collection view and check its class type.

If the received view is indeed your header you will need to check its frame in comparison to your collection view and see if its position is on top. To do so you may convert frame to your coordinates:

```
func isHeader(headerView: UIView, onTopOfCollectionView collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Bool {
    guard let collectionSuperView = collectionView.superview else {
         return false // Collection view is not in view hierarchy. This will most likely never happen
    }
    let convertedFrame = headerView.convert(headerView.bounds, to: collectionSuperView) // Convert frame of the view to whatever is the superview of collection view
    return convertedFrame.origin.y <= collectionView.frame.origin.y // Compare frame origins
}
```

So I guess the whole thing would be something like:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    collectionView.visibleSupplementaryViews(<#My identifier here#>).forEach { view in
        if let header = view as? MyHeaderView {
            header.hideSecondaryViews = isHeader(headerView: header, onTopOfCollectionView: collectionView)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thank Matic Oblak, It worked . But the header view not update new size. How can I fix it ???

Comment: @Mr.T Not sure. What have you tried? Are you using auto-layout? What defines your height currently? It would probably be best to ask another question adding all the code and description about these...

Comment: this is my project about it . I want when the header stick in the top . Red view and Blue view will be disappear.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WZIwgt1-ct9Z2skiCA0RKXn5mn3rQ0MV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Mr.T Seeing your project I can not imagine what the end result would look like in your case. It seems to me that your view 3 and view 2 should simply be cells instead of headers. Use only view 1 as a header and all other issues are gone for you. Or am I missing something? Think about it, if you hide those 2 views when header gets to top what will you see instead of them? A white color? The bottom part of your header should scroll beneath the top part which means it needs to act like a cell...

Comment: Yes, I think I will create a custom cell for UIView1 and a custom cell for UIView2. It can resolve this problem. Thank you so much :)